# Facebook like or share with dynamic document title

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-like, title

I found this problem all over the net but no answer yet, so maybe here someone solved it ...?
I built a page relying heavily on jquery.address. It's got one index page and the rest loads dynamically via Ajax following Google's `/#!/` scheme for crawlable pages. Now I want to add Facebooks Like or share button but I can't get it to grab the actual page title or url.

Whatever I do, it always falls back to title and url of the index page. It tried:

- (obviously) changing title an openGraph meta on load of the new parts.
- "linking" the crawler page (`?_escaped_fragmet_=xyx`) but specifying the `#!` page in meta
- "sharing" with a given title and url.

I never get anything but a link to the index page or a blank "share" to the right url with title and thumbnail ignored.

Has anyone got a similar setup working?

Thanks for any hints,
thomas

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? since i still couldn't find one either. Facebook does use #! itself but doesn't seem to support it for their crawler right?

Comment: I actually found out that facebook is using #! two days ago. Now it works! If you build your site so that http://site.de/?_escaped_fragment=something is identical to http://site.de/#!/something all you have to do is "share" the #! url and it'll display the info from the escaped fragment page. Use this URL to check: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: You also might want to check https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling for a much cleaner solution.

Comment: cool. why don't you write it down as an answer to your question? people will probably find that more than usefull!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is actually using `#!` now and it works! If you build your site so that http://site.de/?_escaped_fragment=something is identical to http://site.de/#!/something all you have to do is "share" the `#!` url and it'll display the info from the escaped fragment page.
Use this URL to check: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

But: A much cleaner solution to the problem can be found here: http://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that Facebook's crawler doesn't run Javascript and will always display whatever's actually in the page it gets from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook share has a BRUTAL cache, last time I checked it was impossible to change the title / description data once it was scraped :(

Comment: Didn't know about this Lint tool or that it refreshes cache, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was the og:url and the actual url of the page did not match. I also read a number of comments about the og data being just after the title element, but I don't think that solved anything.

With regard to issues of caching, it is true that Facebook's caching is "brutal", but it does not cache anything for the lint tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

I use no-hash-bang urls when sharing links. I process the hard links and redirect them to a hash bang client side using javascript. That way if a crawler goes to the hard linked page it will display the information just as it would if javascript were enabled.

Compare:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flikeapage.com%2F%23!%2FChristmas%2Fvs%2FBacon

and

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flikeapage.com%2FChristmas%2Fvs%2FBacon

Hope this helps.